# POST to server with custom URL?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to connect with my server to pass a POST request in JSON.

The URL I send it to, however, depends on the id being viewed on the template. So if I'm looking at a "group" with the ID 1100, the URL should be:

`http://localhost:3100/api/groups/1100/something/start.`

I just can't figure out how to get the group id in there. Trying, but no dice (well, because I don't know how I should properly define `params`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
         url: "/api/groups/"+ params.group_id +"/something/start",
         type: 'post',
             contentType: 'application/json',
             dataType: 'json'
                  });
                  },
```

Some more useful info:

My route:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({                                                                                  
 sortProperties: ['id'],                                                                                              
 sortAscending: true,                                                                                                 

  actions: {                                                                                                           
toggleMenu: function() {                                                                                           
  this.controller.toggleProperty('menuVisible');                                                                   
  this.controller.pushBody();                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                  
  },                                                                                                                   

  model: function() {                                                                                                  
var store = this.store;                                                                                            
var url = '/api/groups/top?subscribe=true';                                                   
$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {                                                                               
  store.pushMany('group', data.data.groups); 


});
 return this.store.all('group');                                                                                                                
  }

});
```

Controller:

```
App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
 sortProperties: ['name'],
sortAscending: true,
 menuVisible: false,     
 actions: {
 poweron: function(){
         jQuery.ajax({
             url: "/api/groups/"+ params.group_id +"/something/start",
             type: 'post',
                 contentType: 'application/json',
                 dataType: 'json'
                      });
                      }

});
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What you have should work fine, if params is an object with a group_id key that has the value of your groupid.

Comment: I've added the controller and route above. Still getting `params is not defined ` though. Thanks!

Comment: well, did you define `params`? Why do you need `params`? why cant you just pass the `goup_id`?

Comment: I think that's my problem - I'm unfamiliar with how to do that, and haven't had luck with searches. Maybe I don't need `params` - I just thought that was how it's done. Popping `group_id` in there gives me similarly, `group_id is not defined`.

Comment: Where is your group_id stored? how do you know what group_id to use?

Comment: Thanks - your line of questioning helped me realize I was thinking about about the variable wrong. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I needed to pass along the `id` argument to the controller - how else would the controller know which `id` to use?

More - http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-parameters

The correct action looks more like this:

```
actions: {
poweron: function(id){
       group_id = id;
       alert(group_id); //let's see what's being sent over

         jQuery.ajax({
             url: "/api/groups/"+ group_id +"/something/start",
             type: 'post',

 ........etc and so on.
```

Comment: don't forget the `var` keyword before `group_id = id`. or better yet, accept your id as group_id `poweron: function(group_id){` so that you don't create the extra var